# Using unlabelled custom images instead of Mnist and CIFAR for a simple GAN with Pytorch

Tags: python, image, pytorch, mnist, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to replace standardized data from pytorch such as MNIST and CIFAR with unlabeled custom images in png format in a simple GAN. Unfortunately most examples always use such datasets and dont show the process of preparing and implementing custom data into GANs.  I have stored my  png-images (336*336, RGB) in the working directory of VS Code. Could you please provide me with a suggestion on how to go forward? Below you find the current code where I would like to replace mnist with my own images to generate new images (from #Preparing Training Data to #Plotting Samples:

```
import torch
from torch import nn

import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms

torch.manual_seed(111)

# DEVICE
device = ""
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    device = torch.device("cuda")
else:
    device = torch.device("cpu")

print(device)

***# PREPARING TRAINING DATA

transform = transforms.Compose(
    [transforms.ToTensor(), transforms.Normalize((0.5,), (0.5,))]
)

#  LOADING DATA
train_set = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(
    root=".", train=True, download=True, transform=transform
)

# CREATE DATALOADER

batch_size = 32
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    train_set, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True
)***

# PLOTTING SAMPLES

real_samples, mnist_labels = next(iter(train_loader))
for i in range(16):
    ax = plt.subplot(4, 4, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(real_samples[i].reshape(28, 28), cmap="gray_r")
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.show()´

# IMPLEMENTING DISCRIMINATOR AND GENERATOR


class Discriminator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(784, 1024),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Dropout(0.3),
            nn.Linear(1024, 512),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Dropout(0.3),
            nn.Linear(512, 256),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Dropout(0.3),
            nn.Linear(256, 1),
            nn.Sigmoid(),
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.view(x.size(0), 784)
        output = self.model(x)
        return output


discriminator = Discriminator().to(device=device)


class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(100, 256),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(256, 512),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(512, 1024),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(1024, 784),
            nn.Tanh(),
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        output = self.model(x)
        output = output.view(x.size(0), 1, 28, 28)
        return output


generator = Generator().to(device=device)

# TRAINING PARAMS

lr = 0.0001
num_epochs = 100
loss_function = nn.BCELoss()

optimizer_discriminator = torch.optim.Adam(discriminator.parameters(), lr=lr)
optimizer_generator = torch.optim.Adam(generator.parameters(), lr=lr)

# TRAINING LOOP

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for n, (real_samples, mnist_labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
        # Data for training the discriminator
        real_samples = real_samples.to(device=device)
        real_samples_labels = torch.ones((batch_size, 1)).to(
            device=device
        )
        latent_space_samples = torch.randn((batch_size, 100)).to(
            device=device
        )
        generated_samples = generator(latent_space_samples)
        generated_samples_labels = torch.zeros((batch_size, 1)).to(
            device=device
        )
        all_samples = torch.cat((real_samples, generated_samples))
        all_samples_labels = torch.cat(
            (real_samples_labels, generated_samples_labels)
        )

        # Training the discriminator
        discriminator.zero_grad()
        output_discriminator = discriminator(all_samples)
        loss_discriminator = loss_function(
            output_discriminator, all_samples_labels
        )
        loss_discriminator.backward()
        optimizer_discriminator.step()

        # Data for training the generator
        latent_space_samples = torch.randn((batch_size, 100)).to(
            device=device
        )

        # Training the generator
        generator.zero_grad()
        generated_samples = generator(latent_space_samples)
        output_discriminator_generated = discriminator(generated_samples)
        loss_generator = loss_function(
            output_discriminator_generated, real_samples_labels
        )
        loss_generator.backward()
        optimizer_generator.step()

        # Show loss
        if n == batch_size - 1:
            print(f"Epoch: {epoch} Loss D.: {loss_discriminator}")
            print(f"Epoch: {epoch} Loss G.: {loss_generator}")

# SAMPLES

latent_space_samples = torch.randn(batch_size, 100).to(device=device)
generated_samples = generator(latent_space_samples)

generated_samples = generated_samples.cpu().detach()
for i in range(16):
    ax = plt.subplot(4, 4, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(generated_samples[i].reshape(28, 28), cmap="gray_r")
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.show()´´´
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example that you shared above, you are trying to train your generator on single-channel images. Specifically, your Generator and Discriminator layers are written to handle images of dimension `1x28x28` which are the dimensions of MNIST or Fashion-MNIST datasets.

I am supposing that you are trying to train color images (3 channels) or a different dimension, in your case - `3x336x336`. In your example, I have added a `tensor transform` that first converts an input image of any dimension to an image of dimension - `3x28x28`.

Here are the code examples for creating the custom dataset and custom dataloader.

```
from glob import glob
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from torchvision import transforms
from skimage import io

path = 'your/image/path'
image_paths = glob(path + '/*.jpg')

img_size = 28
batch_size = 32

transform = transforms.Compose(
        [
            transforms.ToPILImage(),
            transforms.Resize(img_size),
            transforms.CenterCrop(img_size),
            transforms.ToTensor(),
            transforms.Normalize([0.5, 0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5, 0.5]),
        ]
    )

class ImageDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, paths, transform):
        self.paths = paths
        self.transform = transform
        
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.paths)
    

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        image_path = self.paths[index]
        image = io.imread(image_path)
        
        if self.transform:
            image_tensor = self.transform(image)
            
        return image_tensor

dataset = ImageDataset(image_paths, transform)
    
train_loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=1, shuffle=True)
```

The dataloader generates image tensors of dimension - `batch_size x img_channels x img_dim x img_dim` which in this case would be - `32x3x28x28`.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'

class Discriminator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(784*3, 2048),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Dropout(0.3),
            nn.Linear(2048, 1024),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Dropout(0.3),
            nn.Linear(1024, 512),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Dropout(0.3),
            nn.Linear(512, 256),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Dropout(0.3),
            nn.Linear(256, 1),
            nn.Sigmoid(),
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.view(x.size(0), 784*3) # change required for 3 channel image
        output = self.model(x)
        return output


discriminator = Discriminator().to(device=device)


class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(100, 256),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(256, 512),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(512, 1024),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(1024, 2048),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(2048, 784*3),
            nn.Tanh(),
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        output = self.model(x)
        output = output.view(x.size(0), 3, 28, 28)
        return output


generator = Generator().to(device=device)

# TRAINING PARAMS

lr = 0.0001
num_epochs = 100
loss_function = nn.BCELoss()

optimizer_discriminator = torch.optim.Adam(discriminator.parameters(), lr=lr)
optimizer_generator = torch.optim.Adam(generator.parameters(), lr=lr)
```

This is the code for Generator and Discriminator. I have made slight modifications to the Generator and Discriminator. Notice the addition of the following layers in the Discriminator

```
nn.Linear(784*3, 2048),
nn.ReLU(),
nn.Dropout(0.3),
nn.Linear(2048, 1024),
```

and these in the Generator

```
nn.Linear(1024, 2048),
nn.ReLU(),
nn.Linear(2048, 784*3)
```

This is required to generate and discriminate images of the correct dimension.

Finally, this is your training loop -

```
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for n, real_samples in enumerate(train_loader):
        # Data for training the discriminator
        real_samples = real_samples.to(device=device)
        real_samples_labels = torch.ones((batch_size, 1)).to(
            device=device
        )
        latent_space_samples = torch.randn((batch_size, 100)).to(
            device=device
        )
        print(f'Latent space samples : {latent_space_samples.shape}')
        generated_samples = generator(latent_space_samples)
        generated_samples_labels = torch.zeros((batch_size, 1)).to(
            device=device
        )
        all_samples = torch.cat((real_samples, generated_samples))
        print(f'Real samples : {real_samples.shape}, generated samples : {generated_samples.shape}')
        all_samples_labels = torch.cat(
            (real_samples_labels, generated_samples_labels)
        )

        # Training the discriminator
        discriminator.zero_grad()
        output_discriminator = discriminator(all_samples)
        loss_discriminator = loss_function(
            output_discriminator, all_samples_labels
        )
        loss_discriminator.backward()
        optimizer_discriminator.step()

        # Data for training the generator
        latent_space_samples = torch.randn((batch_size, 100)).to(
            device=device
        )

        # Training the generator
        generator.zero_grad()
        generated_samples = generator(latent_space_samples)
        output_discriminator_generated = discriminator(generated_samples)
        loss_generator = loss_function(
            output_discriminator_generated, real_samples_labels
        )
        loss_generator.backward()
        optimizer_generator.step()

        # Show loss
        if n == batch_size - 1:
            print(f"Epoch: {epoch} Loss D.: {loss_discriminator}")
            print(f"Epoch: {epoch} Loss G.: {loss_generator}")
```

This works because the images are reshaped from the `784*3` to the `3*28*28` dimension.

This would work but if you are handling images of 3 channels, you would need to write `ConvTranspose2d` and `Conv2d` operations in your Generator and Discriminator for upsampling and downsampling the image respectively.

If you are interested in an example that uses `ConvTranspose2d` and `Conv2d` for processing multidimensional images, here it is - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gYiBHPu-r3kialO0klsTdE2RjBR50rMs/view?usp=sharing. To handle images of different dimensions, you would have to modify the layers in the Generator and Discriminator classes.

Comment: Thanks you so much. I implemented the code and tried to run it.     
I received a RuntimeError:  Attempt has been made to start a new process before the current process has finished its bootstrapping phase. This probably means that you are not using fork to start your child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom in the main module: if __name__ == '__main__':   freeze_support()
I added if __name__ == '__main__': in front of the code but then received an AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'ImageDataset' on <module '__mp_main__' . How can I solve this? This is  a challenge :D

Comment: This code works fine on linux. Are you on windows by any chance? In that case, can you try putting everything inside functions and adding the main module? That should solve the issue you are facing.

Comment: Was able to solve the above issue. Now i get the following error in the line "loss_discriminator = loss_function(output_discriminator, all_samples_labels)'' though:ValueError: Using a target size (torch.Size([64, 1])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([47, 1])) is deprecated. Please ensure they have the same size.  I dont get at all where that is coming from :( @Aditya: You diodnt have that problem?

Comment: No, I didn't face this issue. Could it be because of different batch sizes? Also, was the model able to train at least for a few steps or it spit out the error in the first step itself?

Comment: t only made it through one epoch and then gave me the error. Are u referring to the batch sizes 32 vs 100 for latent space? Could you explain why they are different ?! May it also be the case that the GAN becomes unstable that quickly, it happens every time after Epoch 0. I have posted the question here, too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72791888/value-error-torch-target-size-and-torch-input-size-in-gan-do-not-match

Comment: Hi @Sterik, I added an answer to your question at the link you pasted above.

Comment: Thank you! I am on it already :) Could you please let me know why the different batch sizes as mentioned above? The generator creates batches of 100 and the discriminator uses batches of 10 or am i getting that wrong?

Comment: So 100 is the dimension of the noise vector. In this particular example, we are using a batch size of 32. Let's say you have 320 examples in your dataset and a batch_size of 32. The dataloader would load 32 samples from a total of 320 samples and the model trains on these 32 samples (batch_size). This would repeat for 10 steps after which the epoch is completed (the model has seen the entire data at least once). Consider, the number of samples are 330. In this case, the model would 32 samples for 10 steps and the remaining 10 samples in the last step of an epoch.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I mixed that up with the noise vector. Ah, I get it! So the remaining 10 are a problem for the last epoch as the batch is strictly set to 32 but only 10 remain, right? The script is still running and your fix works as far as i can tell. Sorry I have another question in that context; How many images is the generator creating per Epoch? Same amount as the discriminator sees or how does that work? I appreciate your help a lot as I am very new to thi sexciting field. Thank you so much!

Comment: The generator is creating batch_size images in every step. An epoch consists of a certain number of steps which would be ceil(total_samples/batch_size). You can then generate an arbitrary number of images using your generator once the entire setup is trained.