# Value Error: Torch target size and torch input size in GAN do not match

Tags: python, pytorch, valueerror, generative-adversarial-network

Hi I  am working on a GAN with custom images. I got the following error, which doesn't add up for me:

**ValueError: Using a target size (torch.Size([64, 1])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([47, 1])) is deprecated. Please ensure they have the same size.**

I do not see where either of these sizes come from. Could someone please help me out? The error is to be found at the loss_disrimenator in the course of the training (marked with an arrow) after epoch 0. Below you find the related code. I am using vs code windows.

Also is it normal that epoch 0 works and then the problem appears?

[Sceenshot of Terminal- Epoch 0 Loss Discriminatorand Generator][1]

```
import torch
from glob import glob
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from torchvision import transforms
from skimage import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


path = 'Punks'
image_paths = glob(path + '/*.png')

img_size = 28
batch_size = 32

transform = transforms.Compose(
    [
        transforms.ToPILImage(),
        transforms.Resize(img_size),
        transforms.CenterCrop(img_size),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize([0.5, 0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5, 0.5]),
    ]
)


class ImageDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, paths, transform):
        self.paths = paths
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.paths)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        image_path = self.paths[index]
        image = io.imread(image_path)

        if self.transform:
            image_tensor = self.transform(image)

        return image_tensor


if __name__ == '__main__':

    dataset = ImageDataset(image_paths, transform)

    train_loader = DataLoader(
        dataset, batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=1, shuffle=True)

    # PLOTTING SAMPLES

    real_samples = next(iter(train_loader))
    for i in range(9):
        ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, 3 + 1)
        plt.imshow(real_samples[i].reshape(28, 28, 3))
        plt.xticks([])
        plt.yticks([])
        plt.show()

    device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'

    class Discriminator(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.model = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Linear(784*3, 2048),
                nn.ReLU(),
                nn.Dropout(0.3),
                nn.Linear(2048, 1024),
                nn.ReLU(),
                nn.Dropout(0.3),
                nn.Linear(1024, 512),
                nn.ReLU(),
                nn.Dropout(0.3),
                nn.Linear(512, 256),
                nn.ReLU(),
                nn.Dropout(0.3),
                nn.Linear(256, 1),
                nn.Sigmoid(),
            )

        def forward(self, x):
            x = x.view(x.size(0), 784*3)  # change required for 3 channel image
            output = self.model(x)
            return output

    discriminator = Discriminator().to(device=device)

    class Generator(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.model = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Linear(100, 256),
                nn.ReLU(),
                nn.Linear(256, 512),
                nn.ReLU(),
                nn.Linear(512, 1024),
                nn.ReLU(),
                nn.Linear(1024, 2048),
                nn.ReLU(),
                nn.Linear(2048, 784*3),
                nn.Tanh(),
            )

        def forward(self, x):
            output = self.model(x)
            output = output.view(x.size(0), 3, 28, 28)
            return output

    generator = Generator().to(device=device)

    # TRAINING PARAMS

    lr = 0.0001
    num_epochs = 10
    loss_function = nn.BCELoss()

    optimizer_discriminator = torch.optim.Adam(discriminator.parameters(), lr=lr)
    optimizer_generator = torch.optim.Adam(generator.parameters(), lr=lr)
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        for n, real_samples in enumerate(train_loader):
            # Data for training the discriminator
            real_samples = real_samples.to(device=device)
            real_samples_labels = torch.ones((batch_size, 1)).to(
                device=device
            )
            latent_space_samples = torch.randn((batch_size, 100)).to(
                device=device
            )
            print(f'Latent space samples : {latent_space_samples.shape}')
            generated_samples = generator(latent_space_samples)
            generated_samples_labels = torch.zeros((batch_size, 1)).to(
                device=device
            )
            all_samples = torch.cat((real_samples, generated_samples))
            print(f'Real samples : {real_samples.shape}, generated samples : {generated_samples.shape}')
            all_samples_labels = torch.cat(
                (real_samples_labels, generated_samples_labels)
            )

            # Training the discriminator
            discriminator.zero_grad()
            output_discriminator = discriminator(all_samples)
            loss_discriminator = loss_function(
                output_discriminator, all_samples_labels
            )
 ------->    loss_discriminator.backward()
            optimizer_discriminator.step()

            # Data for training the generator
            latent_space_samples = torch.randn((batch_size, 100)).to(
                device=device
            )

            # Training the generator
            generator.zero_grad()
            generated_samples = generator(latent_space_samples)
            output_discriminator_generated = discriminator(generated_samples)
            loss_generator = loss_function(
                output_discriminator_generated, real_samples_labels
            )
            loss_generator.backward()
            optimizer_generator.step()

            # Show loss
            if n == batch_size - 1:
                print(f"Epoch: {epoch} Loss D.: {loss_discriminator}")
                print(f"Epoch: {epoch} Loss G.: {loss_generator}")

    latent_space_samples = torch.randn(batch_size, 100).to(device=device)
    generated_samples = generator(latent_space_samples)

    generated_samples = generated_samples.cpu().detach()
    for i in range(9):
        ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
        plt.imshow(generated_samples[i].reshape(28, 28, 3))
        plt.xticks([])
        plt.yticks([])
        plt.show()´´´
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is happening at the end of the first epoch, what's essentially happening is that you have specified a batch size of `64` but the number of images in your dataset is `some_integer_number * 64 + 47`. This is because when you read the data in batches, the number of samples equal to your `batch_size` is read. However, when you reach the end of the epoch, there is a possibility that fewer than `batch_size` examples are left to load.

In your code, the number of generated images in the last step of the 0th epoch is 47 whereas the number of fake images that you are generating is 64 since you use `batch_size` to sample `batch_size` number of fake images.

A simple solution would be to use `len(real_samples)` in place of `batch_size` at all the places. You can do this by first setting `batch_size=len(real_samples)` as the first line in the `for` loop.

```
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
   for n, real_samples in enumerate(train_loader):
      # Data for training the discriminator
      batch_size = len(real_samples)
      real_samples = real_samples.to(device=device)
      real_samples_labels = torch.ones((batch_size, 1)).to(device=device)

      # rest of the code continues
```

I hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Thank you very much i will try that and share if it worked !!! I aprreciate the help very much.

Comment: I set the Epochs to 10 just to see if the code runs through. At the end of epoch 9I now received this RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (16x32 and 100x256) referring to  generated_samples = generator(latent_space_samples) at the pretty end of the code. Whats the problem here now? Oh man...sorry for all the questions.

Comment: These are the offending lines when you are trying to infer after your training is over -- latent_space_samples = torch.randn(batch_size, 100).to(device=device)
    generated_samples = generator(latent_space_samples). You need to create latent_space_samples in the same way that you did above - latent_space_samples = torch.randn((batch_size, 100)).to(
                device=device
            ). In essence, your inference code should use the same dimension as your training code.

Comment: Sorry, I am generally pretty new to all of this. What does infer after training mean? So basically I should replace:                                                      
   "latent_space_samples = torch.randn(batch_size, 32).to(device=device)
    generated_samples = generator(latent_space_samples)"  at the end oof codewith                            
 "latent_space_samples = torch.randn((batch_size, 100)).to(device=device) ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. Also, I can suggest that you can also start with simpler codebases than GANs to get an idea about the training, the matrix multiplication operations etc. Feel free to go through this repo which trains a simple MLP - https://github.com/skymanaditya1/DeepLearning Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I know...i wanted too much too early and am following this GAN in course of a project I have to submit over the weekend. In this context, I have a very demanding question. Would you maybe be open to reviewing my project and maybe discussing it with me in the following two days? That would be such a great help. I am follwoing your github now and will look at the examples you provide afterwards. :)