# pytorch.info summary for Generator of AN equivalent to discriminator or summary for whole GAN

Tags: pytorch, summary, generative-adversarial-network

Is it possible to generate a summary for the generator network of a GAN equivalent to the summary for the discriminator network using pytorch.info (containing inputs and outputs) or is there even a standard summary for the whole GAN including both networks?

For the Discriminator I used the following:

```
model = Discriminator()
batch_size = 32
summary(model, input_size=(batch_size, 3, 28, 28))
```

and received the following summary, which I would also like for the generator (see below summary):

```
==========================================================================================
Layer (type:depth-idx)                   Output Shape              Param #
==========================================================================================
Discriminator                            [32, 1]                   --
├─Sequential: 1-1                        [32, 1]                   --
│    └─Linear: 2-1                       [32, 2048]                4,818,944
│    └─ReLU: 2-2                         [32, 2048]                --
│    └─Dropout: 2-3                      [32, 2048]                --
│    └─Linear: 2-4                       [32, 1024]                2,098,176
│    └─ReLU: 2-5                         [32, 1024]                --
│    └─Dropout: 2-6                      [32, 1024]                --
│    └─Linear: 2-7                       [32, 512]                 524,800
│    └─ReLU: 2-8                         [32, 512]                 --
│    └─Dropout: 2-9                      [32, 512]                 --
│    └─Linear: 2-10                      [32, 256]                 131,328
│    └─ReLU: 2-11                        [32, 256]                 --
│    └─Dropout: 2-12                     [32, 256]                 --
│    └─Linear: 2-13                      [32, 1]                   257
│    └─Sigmoid: 2-14                     [32, 1]                   --
==========================================================================================´´´
Total params: 7,573,505
Trainable params: 7,573,505
Non-trainable params: 0
Total mult-adds (M): 242.35
==========================================================================================
Input size (MB): 0.30
Forward/backward pass size (MB): 0.98
Params size (MB): 30.29
Estimated Total Size (MB): 31.58
==========================================================================================
```

For the generator I used the following to create a summary and unfortunately I wasnt able to includ ethe column for output shape as well as everything under and including the input row (as above):

```
model = Generator()
batch_size = 32
summary(model, output_size=(batch_size, 3, 28, 28))
```

and received the following shorter summary:

```
=================================================================
Layer (type:depth-idx)                   Param #
=================================================================
Generator                                --
├─Sequential: 1-1                        --
│    └─Linear: 2-1                       25,856
│    └─ReLU: 2-2                         --
│    └─Linear: 2-3                       131,584
│    └─ReLU: 2-4                         --
│    └─Linear: 2-5                       525,312
│    └─ReLU: 2-6                         --
│    └─Linear: 2-7                       2,099,200
│    └─ReLU: 2-8                         --
│    └─Linear: 2-9                       4,819,248
│    └─Tanh: 2-10                        --
=================================================================
Total params: 7,601,200
Trainable params: 7,601,200
Non-trainable params: 0
=================================================================
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This package is not recommended for debugging your code, you should therefore always make sure your code runs on random data before testing the summary.

In the second group of commands, you are using `output_size` instead of `input_size` (cf. [src](https://github.com/TylerYep/torchinfo/blob/main/torchinfo/torchinfo.py#L54)). Looking at your code for `Generator`, the input shape should be `(batch_size, 100)`. Additionally your final linear layer should output a total of `3*28*28` values in order for you to reshape to an image of shape `(3, 28, 28)`.

```
class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(100, 256),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(256, 512),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(512, 1024),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(1024, 2048),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(2048, 28*28*3),
            nn.Tanh(),
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        output = self.model(x)
        output = output.view(x.size(0), 3, 28, 28)
        return output
```

Which you can summarize with:

```
>>> summary(model, input_size=(10,100))
========================================================================================
Layer (type:depth-idx)                   Output Shape              Param #
========================================================================================
Generator                                [10, 3, 28, 28]           --
├─Sequential: 1-1                        [10, 2352]                --
│    └─Linear: 2-1                       [10, 256]                 25,856
│    └─ReLU: 2-2                         [10, 256]                 --
│    └─Linear: 2-3                       [10, 512]                 131,584
│    └─ReLU: 2-4                         [10, 512]                 --
│    └─Linear: 2-5                       [10, 1024]                525,312
│    └─ReLU: 2-6                         [10, 1024]                --
│    └─Linear: 2-7                       [10, 2048]                2,099,200
│    └─ReLU: 2-8                         [10, 2048]                --
│    └─Linear: 2-9                       [10, 2352]                4,819,248
│    └─Tanh: 2-10                        [10, 2352]                --
========================================================================================
Total params: 7,601,200
Trainable params: 7,601,200
Non-trainable params: 0
Total mult-adds (M): 76.01
========================================================================================
Input size (MB): 0.00
Forward/backward pass size (MB): 0.50
Params size (MB): 30.40
Estimated Total Size (MB): 30.90
========================================================================================
```

Comment: It doesn't return anything for input size. That's why I used output size.

Comment: Have you checked the documenation page? Do you know if `output_size` is an actual argument name?

Comment: I have checked it (https://pypi.org/project/torchinfo/) and there isn't that argument. Somehow it is working though. With input_size it just doesn't work for me. The model I am referring to is to be found under this link (other question :D ): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72791888/value-error-torch-target-size-and-torch-input-size-in-gan-do-not-match Do you have an idea how I could make it work otherwise?

Comment: Oh thank you a lot @Ivan. Why do you assume a batch size of 10 for the generator or how did you come up with it? Can that be logically derived? I set it the batch size at the beginning of the code to 32. Does this only relate to the discriminator or how is the batch size set for generators or which one should be used in such summaries? Sorry, that question just popped up now.

Comment: You decide the batch size, it can be any value, and your generator will be asked to generate that amount of images. And same goes for you discriminator.

Comment: So it would be 32 in my case cause I didnt differentiate batchsizes for generator and discriminator. Thanks

Comment: Of course, your discriminator would receive the same number of element inside the batch otherwise it wouldn't make sense.