# Creating an image grid of tensors out of a batch using matplotlib/pytorch

Tags: python, matplotlib, pytorch, grid, tensor

I am trying to create a grid of images (e.g. 3 by 3) from a batch of tensors that will be fed into a GAN through a data loader in the next step. With the below code I was able to transform the tensors into images that are displayed in a grid in the right position. The problem is, that they are all displayed in a separate grid as shown here: [Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSLzG.png) [Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcJWW.png)    [Figure 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIDa5.png). How can put them in one grid and just get one figure returned with all 9 images?? Maybe I am making it too complicated. :D In the end tensors out of the real_samples have to be transformed and put into a grid.

```
real_samples = next(iter(train_loader))
for i in range(9):
    plt.figure(figsize=(9, 9))
    plt.subplot(330 + i + 1)
    plt.imshow(np.transpose(vutils.make_grid(real_samples[i].to(device)
                      [:40], padding=1, normalize=True).cpu(),(1,2,0)))
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

And here is how to display a variable number of wonderful CryptoPunks using matplotlib XD:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

row_count = 3
col_count = 3

cryptopunks = [
    mpimg.imread(f"cryptopunks/{i}.png") for i in range(row_count * col_count)
]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8., 8.))
grid = ImageGrid(fig, 111, nrows_ncols=(row_count, col_count), axes_pad=0.1)

for ax, im in zip(grid, cryptopunks):
    ax.imshow(im)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Please note that the code allows you to generate all the images you want, not only 3 times 3. I have a folder called `cryptopunks` with a lot of images called `#.png` (e.g., `1.png`, ..., `34.png`, ...). Just change the `row_count` and `col_count` variable values. For instance, for `row_count=6` and `col_count=8` you get:
[image]

If your image files do not have that naming pattern above (i.e., just random names), just replace the first lines with the following ones:

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

for root, _, filenames in os.walk("cryptopunks/"):
    cryptopunks = [
        mpimg.imread(Path(root, filename)) for filename in filenames
    ]

row_count = 3
col_count = 3

# Here same code as above.
```

(I have downloaded the CryptoPunks dataset from [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/tunguz/cryptopunks?resource=download).)

Comment: I am struggling a bit as I am pretty new to this. I got a grid done but still wasnt able to solve the problem entrirely. I adapted the initial post. Would appreciate your help!

Comment: With the code above you can create with the size you like, not only 3 times 3. Moreover, at the end of the answer you can find the code to read a files with random names.

Comment: Hehe thank you! ;) Actually, I think I didnt state my problem right. I have tensors after my original pictures have been loaded and transformed into a tensor and now i would like to display a selection of the next batch that will be going through my network in  a grid. I will update my question accordingly. Many thanks for the effort!

Comment: I am sorry, I am not understanding. What's missing in my answer? Thanks!

Comment: The transformation of tensors to images before putting them in a grid. I am doing thsi in the course of running a generative adversarial network and every epoch this has to be done.

Comment: Ok, got it. But I cannot reproduce your example so it's a lot more difficult to me to understand how to properly help you. Are you getting an error? Provide more details, please. Thanks!

Comment: What's `real_samples`? A numpy array, etc?

Comment: real_samples contains tensors from the model that I have asked a question about here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72791888/value-error-torch-target-size-and-torch-input-size-in-gan-do-not-match you find the part I focus on here under #plotting samples.  the tensors were created when transforming images to other dimensionality and I have the same problem later on when I want to plot the images generated by the generator network (e.g. at #show loss at the bottom of the code)

Answer (score 1):

For a 9 image grid you probably want three rows and three columns. Probably the simplest way to do that is something like so:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=3)
axes = axes.flatten() # Flattens the array so you can access individual axes

for ax in axes:
    # Do stuff with your individual axes here
    plt.show() # This call is here just for example, prob. better call outside of the loop
```

which outputs the following axes configuration with `plt.tight_layout()`:

[image: 3x3 image grid]

You might also be interested in the [matplotlib mosaic](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot_mosaic.html) functionality or [gridspec one](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec.html). Hope this helps.

EDIT: Here's a solution which annotates each plot with its number so you can see what goes where as well:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=3)
axes = axes.flatten()

for idx, ax in enumerate(axes):
    ax.annotate(f"{idx+1}", xy=(0.5, 0.5), xytext=(0.5, 0.5))
```

[image: with annotations]

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib provides a function called subplot, I think this is what you are searching for!

plt.subplot(9,1) is the syntax I guess.

And then configure your plots

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).